# Check if product with sku exists in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1.x I could do

```
if(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku))
```

How can I check this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```php
try {
    $product = $productRepository->get($sku);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
    $product = false;
}
```

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

if($product->getIdBySku($sku)) {
    echo 'exit';    
}
```

**OR**

```
protected $product;
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->_product = $product;
    }
```

and after check

```
if($this->_product->getIdBySku($sku)) {
    echo 'exit';    
}
```

Comment: I thought you shouldn't use the objectManager directly

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: 2nd version without the object manager is better :)

Answer (score 1):

See @bpoiss answer, my answer is more about how to get a product using the sku.

To do so you can use the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` class.

First inject it in your constructor:

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(/* your original parameters here */, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository)
{
    /* your original code here */
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    /* end of your original code */
}
```

Then in your function you can do:

```
$this->_productRepository->get($sku);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because if the sku exists i got an instance of ProductInterface and otherwise the string 'Product does not exist' which evaluetes to true. I would have to do an additional instance check

Comment: @bpoiss yeah that's right my answer is more about how to get a product from the sku, your answer is definitely the right one ;) Btw, you can tick the 'answer my question' when you create a new question so you will have only one form to fill ;)

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, but in the moment I wrote the question I did not know the answer ^^

Comment: @bpoiss haha ok ^^ as your answer was quick I guessed you knew it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the `getIdBySku` method still exists in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`. Inject it with

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
) {
    $this->productModel = $productModel;
}
```

and than you can check with

```
$this->productModel->getIdBySku($sku)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

```
$checkProduct = $this->objectManager->create(
                'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
            );
    if($checkProduct->getIdBySku()){
    echo 'exist';
    }
```

But it is not the standard function.