# Identify weather the product is new or getting update on save

Tags: magento2

I have created an observer on "controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after" where I am getting the product which is being saved. what i want is to identify that the product which is being saved is it a new or old being update.

```
namespace Commersys\ZohoInventorySync\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class NewProductSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        var_dump($_product->getData());
        die();
    }
}
```

in events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
        <observer name="newProductSaveObserver" instance="Commersys\ZohoInventorySync\Observer\NewProductSaveObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `after` event doesn't work for your case. We should use `catalog_product_save_before` and get product id or sku and check if it is exist or not by using product repository.

Use this link for [check product existence by sku](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106902/check-if-product-with-sku-exists-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use the event like:

> `catalog_product_save_after`

***And at this observer,you can get  identify by below code***

```
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         /** @var Product $product */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if($product->isObjectNew() )
        {//new product
        }
    }
```